# CSS for labels and input fields of a form. What is still going wrong?

Tags: html, css, input, tags

I am trying to align the input fields of a form like in [How it should be actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NibZt.png) but I have not been able to get it done.

You can see the code that I have done so far, but still it does not work.

What am I missing?

```css
label.gegevens {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 350px;
    text-align: left;
}

input.gegevens {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  clear:left;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Naam: </span><input type="text" name="FirstName" required></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Adres: </span><input type="text" name="Adres" required></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Postcode: </span><input type="text" name="postcode" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[A-Z]{2}" required></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Woonplaats: </span><input type="text" name="Woonplaats" required></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Email: </span><input type="text" name="Email"></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Genwenste leverdatum: </span><input id="date" type="date" name="Leverdatum"></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Bestand: </span><input type="file" name="Bestand"></label></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Bestellen">
</form>
```

Comment: So where's the class gegevens? It doesn't appear anywhere in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a div around the form and then floating the inputs to the right. Here's what I did:

```
<div id="box">
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Naam: </span><input type="text" name="FirstName" required></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Adres: </span><input type="text" name="Adres" required></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Postcode: </span><input type="text" name="postcode" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[A-Z]{2}" required></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Woonplaats: </span><input type="text" name="Woonplaats" required></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Email: </span><input type="text" name="Email"></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Genwenste leverdatum: </span><input id="date" type="date" name="Leverdatum"></label></p>
        <p><label><span class="client-info">Bestand: </span><input type="file" name="Bestand"></label></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Bestellen">
</form>
```

and here's the CSS

```
label.gegevens {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 200px;
text-align: left;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  clear:right;
  text-align:right;
}

#box {
  width:50%
}
```

[Link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/torekijola/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code a little. One of the problems was `label.gegevens` while that class wasn't used. I changed it to `label.client-info`.

I use a flexbox for the layout and vertical alignment of the line elements. To learn more about flexbox have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I don't use floats to keep all elements in the document flow.

Please note: flexbox may cause issues when using IE11 or lower.

```css
label.client-info {
  width: 180px;
}

form p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">
  <p><label class="client-info">Naam:</label><input type="text" name="FirstName" required></p>
  <p><label class="client-info">Adres:</label><input type="text" name="Adres" required></p>
  <p><label class="client-info">Postcode:</label><input type="text" name="postcode" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[A-Z]{2}" required></p>
  <p><label class="client-info">Woonplaats:</label><input type="text" name="Woonplaats" required></p>
  <p><label class="client-info">Email:</label><input type="text" name="Email"></p>
  <p><label class="client-info">Genwenste leverdatum:</label><input id="date" type="date" name="Leverdatum"></p>
  <p><label class="client-info">Bestand:</label><input type="file" name="Bestand"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Bestellen">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c04wLvn3/2/)

```
input{
  position:absolute;
  right:50%;
  left:200px;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation (in your answer) as to why this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 350px;
    text-align: left;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  clear:left;
  text-align:right;
}
```

I notice you had used both the form element and class name, but you don't need a class name for this CSS. If you would need special CSS properties for an element, then you should use a class.

Comment: Please add an explanation why this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks trincot for your suggestion. I was tried this code with him htmls.  He can use html element hes hasn't need a class or id. I hope u can use too .

Comment: I meant: please edit your answer, and add an explanation in the answer.

Comment: I made. sorry sir trincot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I wanted to achieve (see codes). Now I do not know how to make it responsive. In shorter viewports, everything gets messy. Any tips for this?

```css
html {
  background-image: url(boeken.jpeg); 
  background-size: cover;
}

span.list {
  color:white; 
  background:black;
  padding:4px;
  margin-right:5px;
}

input#opt1, input#opt2, input#opt3 {
  width:10px;
}

input#karen, input#paula {
  width:20px;
  border: #03A9F4;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  margin-left:5px;
}

input#esther {
  width:120px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  margin-left:5px;
  z-index:10;
}

select#lijst-fail, input#naam, input#adres, input#postcode, input#woonplaats, input#email, input#date {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

small {
  margin-left:10px;
}

form input {
  width: 300px;
  border: #03A9F4;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.button-verzenden {
  position:absolute;
  top:35%;
  padding-left:80%;
  z-index:-10;
}

div#section-1 p {display:flex; align-items: center;}

label#karen, label#paula, label#esther, label#suzanne, label#samuel {width:260px;}

div#section-2 p {display:flex; align-items: center;}

div#section-2 label {width:165px;}

input#verzenden {
    background-color: #6d4435;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: #03A9F4;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="file"] {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boeken_bestellen.css">
        <title>Bestel hier uw boeken</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <main>
            
        <header>
        <h1>Boeken bestellen</h1>
            <p>Op deze pagina kunt u snel de boeken bestellen die in de top 5 staan. Geef per boek aan hoeveel u er van wilt bestellen. Sommige boeken zijn er populair en daardoor kunnen we slechts een beperkt aantal boeken naar u toesturen. Dit is aangegeven bij het boek.</p>
        </header>
        
        <div id="section-1">
        <section>
        
        <h2>Bestel hier uw boeken</h2>
        <form id="formulier" action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">
        <p><span class="list">1</span><label for="karen" id="karen">Karin Slaughter - Mooie meisjes:</label><input id="karen" name="karen" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10"><small>Max. 10 exemplaren</small></p>
        
        <p><span class="list">2</span><label for="paula" id="paula">Paula Hawkins - Het meisje in de trein:</label><input id="paula" type="text" name="paula" pattern="[0-9]{2}"><small>Max. 99 exemplaren</small></p>
        
        <p><span class="list">3</span><label for="esther" id="esther">Esther Verhoef - Lieve mama:</label><input id="esther" type="range" min="0" max="15" step="5" list="bereik"><small>Bestel 0, 5, 10 of 15 exemplaren</small>
     <datalist id="bereik">
  <option value="0"> 
  <option value="5">
  <option value="10">
  <option value="15">
  </datalist></p>
            
        <p><span class="list">4</span><label for="suzanne" id="suzanne">Suzanne Vermeer - Costa del Sol:</label>
        <label for="opt1"><input id="opt1" type="radio" name="mw" value="1">1</label>
        <label for="opt2"><input id="opt2" type="radio" name="mw" value="10">10</label>
        <label for="opt3"><input id="opt3" type="radio" name="mw" value="20">20</label>
        </p>
        
        <p><span class="list">5</span><label for="lijst-fail" id="samuel">Samuel Bjork - Ik reis alleen:</label><select id="lijst-fail" name="stijl">
  <option value="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
     </select></p>
        
        </form>
            
        </section>
            
        </div>
            
        <div id="section-2">
        
        <section>
        
        <h2>Geef hier uw adres gegevens op</h2>
        <form id="formulier" action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">               
        <p><label for="naam">Naam: <abbr title="Vereist">*</abbr></label>
     <input id="naam" name="naam" required></p>
        <p><label for="adres">Adres: <abbr title="Vereist">*</abbr></label>
     <input id="adres" name="adres" required></p>
        <p><label for="pc3">Postcode:</label>
     <input id="postcode" name="postcode" pattern="[0-9]{4}\s[A-Z]{2}" title="Een postcode bestaat uit 4 cijfers, 1 spatie en 2 hoofdletters" placeholder="1234 AB"></p>
        <p><label for="woonplaats">Woonplaats: <abbr title="Vereist">*</abbr></label>
     <input id="woonplaats" name="woonplaats" required></p>
        <p><label for="email">Email:</label><input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder=iemand@domein.nl pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"> </p>
        <p><label for="date">Gewenste leverdatum:</label><input id="date" name="date" type="date"></p>
        <p><label for="file">Bestand:</label><input type="file" name="Bestand"></p>
        </form>
        <div class="button-verzenden">
        <input id="verzenden" form="formulier" type="submit" value="Bestellen">    
        </div>
        </section>
        
        </div>
            
        </main>
        
    </body>

</html>
```